# Combinatorial Probability. Have answer looking for explanation.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question:

Consider an experiment with sample space S repeated n times (n ≥ 2). S is a uniform probability space. Let s ∈ S. Let A be the event that the first outcome is s, and let B be the event that the last outcome is s. Prove that A and B are independent.

The answer is

[image: answer]

However I can't for the life of me figure out why P(A) and P(B) is [image: probability of A].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every possible sequence of outcomes $s_1, s_2,\ldots, s_n$ has equal probability, so
\begin{align*}
P(A) &= \frac{\text{number of sequences with first outcome being $s$}}{\text{number of sequences}}
= \frac{|S|^{n-1}}{|S|^n}.
\end{align*}
[For each sample, there are $|S|$ possible outcomes, so for a sequence of $n$ samples there are $|S|^n$ outcomes; this is the denominator. If we know what the first outcome is, we need only consider the possible choices for the remaining $n-1$ samples; this is the numerator.]

Comment: Why is the probability of the first outcome being s dependent on the other n-1 samples? Wouldn't it be the number of permutations of S where s is first over $|S|^n$. Can't wrap my head around the $|S|^{n-1}$

Comment: @FahimAhmed 1. You are right, a much easier way to compute $P(A)$ is to notice that each sample is [presumably] independent of the others, so the probability that the first of $n$ samples is $s$ is simply the probability that one sample is $s$, i.e., $P(A)=1/|S|$.

Comment: @FahimAhmed 2. If you are still confused about where $|S|^{n-1}$ comes from, consider an example where $S=\{H,T\}$ and each sample is a coin flip. How many ways possible sequences of $3$ coin flips are there? There are $2^3=8$. How many sequences of $3$ coin flips have the first flip being a head? There are $2^2=4$ because you only need to count the possibilities for the remaining two flips. List out all the outcomes if you are still not convinced.